# How to open and doc file that has spaces between folder names

Tags: asp.net, href, docx, directory-structure

I have a file that will open perfect when the link is copied to a web browser but will fail when trying to open the link from the web page in asp.net. I noticed its because of the spaces. How can I get my application to read this space in between. The app fails to read Shared Documents due to the spacing and also Microsoft Word Test.docx. What can I add in-between the words that will read those spaces in asp.net so that I can open the docx file. Thanks in advance!

```
http://sharepoint/Shared Documents/Microsoft Word Test.docx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can URL-encode the space character:

```
http://sharepoint/Shared%20Documents/Microsoft%20Word%20Test.docx
```

To do this dynamically in ASP.NET you'd likely use either [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode) or [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode).